# How do I check if GetStringAsync results in a 401 (for instance)?

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following, wher I try to download a string from the server:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var getResponsestring = await client.GetStringAsync("url");
```

But how do I go about and the if the server does not return the string I want, but error 401 for instance? Or any web error for that mather

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpClient.GetStringAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has [Exception property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Update**

When we use async/await we can just wrap the awaitable call in `try/catch` block to handle exceptions.

Comment: Hakonbyan it returns a string? This is valid: string getResponsestring = await client.GetStringAsync, I'm in Portable Class Library if it matters, *confused*

Comment: In your snippet I can't see `await`.

Comment: Even without `await` in the question, this answer doesn't look right to me. Reading a task's result or exception when it has not yet completed is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @hvd, `Result` always returns result. If the asynchronous operation is not completed, `Result` waits and returns on completion.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Right. And that's almost always the wrong thing to do. Blocking until the task completes ignores the whole point of the *Async methods, and can easily cause deadlocks: when the method itself uses `await <task>` and expects to continue on the current thread, yet that thread is blocked, nothing good can happen.

Comment: @hvd, `almost always the wrong thing to do` it is depends on requirements. deadlocks is known issue and easy to avoid them.

Comment: HttpClient does not throw exceptions on either 4XX or 5XX status codes.

Answer (score 19):

You have two choices.  Either break down the request into two steps.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("url");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
  var getResponsestring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

or you insert a new MessageHandler that will return a stock response on errors.

```
var errorMessageHandler = new ErrorMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler());
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(errorMessageHandler);
var getResponsestring = await client.GetStringAsync("url");
```

You will have to implement the ErrorMessageHandler yourself by deriving from a DelegatingHandler and overriding SendAsync.

Comment: within the ErrorMessageHandler how do we force a retry only once if there's a 401?

Comment: @l--''''''---------''''''''''''  You can set a flag in the request properties collection when do the first retry.  When you get a 401 response, check the response.Request.Properties["Retry"] value to see if it is set.  If it is, don't retry again.